# Remove elements from array updating list of stored indexes accordingly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider a `numpy` array of the form:

```
> a = np.random.uniform(0., 100., (10, 1000))
```

and a list of indexes to elements in that array that I want to keep track of:

```
> idx_s = [0, 5, 7, 9, 12, 17, 19, 32, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 41, 42, 45, 47, 51, 53, 57, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 65, 66, 70, 71, 73, 75, 81, 83, 85, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93, 94, 96, 98, 100, 106, 107, 108, 118, 119, 121, 124, 126, 127, 128, 129, 133, 135, 138, 142, 143, 144, 146, 147, 150]
```

I also have a list of indexes of elements I need to remove from `a`:

```
> idx_d = [4, 12, 18, 20, 21, 22, 26, 28, 29, 31, 37, 43, 48, 54, 58, 74, 80, 86, 99, 109, 110, 113, 117, 134, 139, 140, 141, 148, 154, 156, 160, 166, 169, 175, 183, 194, 198, 199, 219, 220, 237, 239, 241, 250]
```

which I delete with:

```
> a_d = np.delete(arr, idx_d, axis=1)
```

But this process alters the indexes of elements in `a_d`. The indexes in `idx_s` no longer point in `a_d` to the same elements in `a`, since `np.delete()` moved them. For example: if I delete the element of index `4` from `a`, then all indexes after `4` in `idx_s` are now displaced by 1 to the right in `a_d`.

```
                 v Index 5 points to 'f' in a
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6
a   -> a b c d e f g ... # Remove 4th element 'e' from a
a_d -> a b c d f g h ... # Now index 5 no longer points to 'f' in a_d, but to 'g'
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

How do I update the `idx_s` list of indexes, so that the same elements that were pointed in `a` are pointed in `a_d`?

In the case of an element that is present in `idx_s` that is **also present** in `idx_d` (and thus removed from `a` and not present in `a_d`) its index should also be discarded.

Comment: instead of deleting them, could you batch-update them all to be 0 or None?

Comment: In a middle step perhaps yes (if it helps achieve the goal), but at some point I do need the `a_d` array with those elements removed from `a`, and the correct indexes of the elements I was tracking.

Comment: A minor change: `a=np.random.uniform(0,100,(10,1000))`

Comment: Done, thank you @hpaulj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to get the shifts for each element in `idx_s`  and then simply subtract those from `idx_s` for the new *shifted-down* values, like so -

```
idx_s - np.searchsorted(idx_d, idx_s)
```

If `idx_d` is not already sorted, we need to feed in a sorted version. Thus, for simplicity assuming these as arrays, we would have -

```
idx_s = idx_s[~np.in1d(idx_s, idx_d)]
out = idx_s - np.searchsorted(np.sort(idx_d), idx_s)
```

A sample run to help out getting a better picture -

```
In [530]: idx_s
Out[530]: array([19,  5, 17,  9, 12,  7,  0])

In [531]: idx_d
Out[531]: array([12,  4, 18])

In [532]: idx_s = idx_s[~np.in1d(idx_s, idx_d)] # Remove matching ones

In [533]: idx_s
Out[533]: array([19,  5, 17,  9,  7,  0])

In [534]: idx_s - np.searchsorted(np.sort(idx_d), idx_s) # Updated idx_s
Out[534]: array([16,  4, 15,  8,  6,  0])
```

Comment: I almost finished this function by myself, but how cool is this! :)

Comment: This works great, but it apparently does not remove elements from `idx_s` that are present in `idx_d` (ie, deleted from `a`). E.g.: `idx_s=[0,  5,  7,  9, 12, 17, 19] ; idx_d= [4, 12, 18]` returns `[0  4  6  8 11 15 16]`. The `12` element is removed, so it should not be present as `11`, it should not be there.

Comment: To explain further: the `12` element in `a` will not be present in the new `a_d` array, so in this case its index needs no updating, it needs to be removed.

Comment: @Gabriel Maybe you should add that part of `removing the matching ones` to the question :)

Comment: I thought I did ("accounting for those elements that were removed"), but obviously I was not clear enough. I'll edit the question now, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar. Am I correct that your answer only works if both `idx_s` and `idx_d` are sorted min to max?

Comment: @Gabriel The current version works for sorted `idx_d`. If its not sorted, we need to use additional arg `sorter` with it? Do you want me to edit for those cases?

Answer (score 1):

```
idx_s = [0, 5, 7, 9, 12, 17, 19]
idx_d = [4, 12, 18]

def worker(a, v, i=0):
    if not a:
        return []
    elif not v:
        return []
    elif a[0] == v[0]:
        return worker(a[1:], v[1:], i+1)
    elif a[0] < v[0]:
        return [a[0]-i] + worker(a[1:], v, i)
    else:
        return [a[0]-i-1] + worker(a[1:], v[1:], i+1)

worker(idx_s, idx_d)
# [0, 5, 6, 8, 15, 16]
```

Comment: Thank you Roman. Would you mind if I edit your answer to remove the `>>>` and the `...`? It makes it easier to copy/paste the code.

Comment: @Gabriel sure go ahead